# How to Align DatagridColumnHeader text depending on the Type of DataGridColumn?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have the following code and I want the DataGrid header text to be left aligned when it is a DataGridComboBoxColumn and centered when it is not.

Style triggers should work, but they don't. Why and what should I do?

<Window.Resources>

```
    <Style  x:Key="CustomColumnHeaderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"  Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="{x:Type DataGridComboBoxColumn}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
    <Style  x:Key="CustomColumnHeaderStyle2" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="200"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Column}" Value="{x:Type DataGridComboBoxColumn}">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>


    <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="myEnum" MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type core:Enum}">
        <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
            <x:Type Type="local:OrderStatus"/>
        </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
    </ObjectDataProvider>
</Window.Resources>
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}"  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource CustomColumnHeaderStyle2}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Order Status"  SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Status}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myEnum}}" />

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Text Column" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Style triggers should work

No. The `Column` property doesn't return a type. And a column is not the `DataContext` of something.

You won't be able to solve this using data triggers and bindings only.

Simply set the `HeaderStyle` of all `DataGridComboBoxColumns` to the following style:

```
<Style x:Key="CenteredCustomColumnHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridColumnHeader}">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

Example:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Order Status"  SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Status}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource myEnum}}"
                        HeaderStyle="{StaticResource CenteredCustomColumnHeaderStyle}"/>
```